# Login. form Back button post data

Tags: button, post, back

I am creating a login form using post method. It is working fine. The logout button work fine. But when I pressed back button the browser and reach the login page where user submit the id and password the resend option is there. Then it resend the id and password again.. How can I overcome the problem.

Comment: if you are using windows back method then you are doing an equivalent of pressing browsers back button(and so you'll see default behavior of browser), go for redirection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to simply redirect the user back to the first page using javascript or server side code.  Don't rely on having to go back in history to get there.

Answer (score 0):

you can't. why do you want to do this anyway? all you need to do is redirect users with a bit of javascript:

```
<script>
window.location = "http://www.yoursite.com/login"
</script>
<noscript>
<a href="http://www.yoursite.com/login">Back to login page</a>
</noscript>
```

the noscript tag is for people that disabled javascript or simply dont have it.